# Reference which explains Penrose Diagramatic notation in simple way

Tags: tensor-calculus, notation

In both Penrose's Road to reality and Spinor's and space-time, the following notation is shown:

[image]

With a lot other examples for doing calculation with Tensors. Could someone give another reference which gives a detailed explanation on how to calculate with these diagrams? The explanations in the books are too fast for me.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/433662/

Comment: Finally! I was going mad searchign fo rthis